# Lightning Utility Bar API locks the utility bar after utilityAPI.minimizeUtility()

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I have been trying to create a simple background utility component in which I also use both, the workspaceAPI and the utilityAPI. I use the workspaceAPI because I want to trigger my process whenever a new Tab is open using `lightning:tabCreated`. Then I use the utilityAPI to minimize a utility component using the method `utilityAPI.minimizeUtility()`.

Although this process successfully minimizes the utility component onTabCreated it then locks all the utility components and prevents them to be open.

Here is my sample code:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:backgroundUtilityItem">
    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar"/>
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>

    <aura:handler event="lightning:tabCreated" action="{! c.onTabCreated }"/>
</aura:component>

onTabCreated: function(component, event, helper) {
    var utilityAPI = component.find("utilitybar");

    if($A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(utilityAPI)){
        return;
    } else {
        utilityAPI.getAllUtilityInfo().then(function(response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].utilityLabel == "Phone") {
                    utilityAPI.minimizeUtility({
                        utilityId: data[i].id
                    });
                }
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('minimize utility bar error: ' + error);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm suspecting there is a bug on any of these APIs, but I wanted to know if anyone has tried to do something similar and have experienced the same issue.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need more information.

--J